# How refers a method inside own parent class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I need to force Python to call a method of the parent class completely ignoring whether or not the child classes have that method overridden.

I don't want to know if my child classes used polymorphism for that function, I just want to call the behavior of the parent class.

Example of how it would look in PHP:

```
<?php

class Dog {
    public function sound() {
        self::prepare();
        echo 'au au!';
    }

    public function prepare() {
        echo 'preparando parent!';
    }
}


class Boxer extends Dog {
    public function sound() {
        parent::sound();
    }

    public function prepare() {
        echo 'preparando box!';
    }
}

$boxer = new Boxer();
$boxer->sound();
```

The output would be:

```
preparando parent!
au au!
```

Note that I'm using **SELF** to tell PHP that I want the PARENT class method. If I wanted to call **PREPARE** from the child class, I could use **$THIS** and then I would have the output:

```
preparando box!
au au!
```

---

I wrote the following class in PYTHON:

```
class Dog:
    def sound(self):
        self.prepare()
        print('au au!')

    def prepare(self):
        print('preparando parent!')

class Boxer(Dog):
    def sound(self):
        super().sound()

    def prepare(self):
        print('preparando box!')

dog = Boxer();
dog.sound()
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
preparando box!
au au!
```

The question is: How do I make my python class behave like PHP when I use **self**?

Comment: `self` in PHP is not the same as `self` in Python, it behave similar to `$this`

Comment: If you want specifically to call the `Dog` implementation of `prepare`, you can use `Dog.prepare(self)`. But you can't make Python behave like php. Different languages work differently.

Comment: And is there any way I can do this without using : **Dog().sound()** ?

Also because, using **Dog** directly from the child class, I completely lose the state of my Boxer class, and that's not what I want.

Comment: If you want `Dog` functionality why do you create `Boxer` instance in the first place?

Comment: try this `Dog.sound(super())` in place of         `super().sound()`

Comment: @Guy - Because in this specific case, Dog can be instantiated.
But, let's think about a scenario where Dog is an abstract class, let's think about the worst-case scenario where I necessarily have to instantiate Boxer.

Comment: @sahasrara62 , using that same idea, I changed it to **Dog.sound(self)** and it worked as I would like! Perfect, it was similar to Javascript when we forced the call with **.call(context)**.

Comment: Well I don't know which cases you have in mined, but this is not how OOP works. You should think carefully on which scenario will make you need to abstract class functionality only using a derived class.

Comment: @JoséVictor this is just a work around, if you want to use parent menthod then you can use them in child class directly considering you didn't override the method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want specifically to call the Dog implementation of prepare, you can use `Dog.prepare(self)`.

```
class Dog:
    def sound(self):
        Dog.prepare(self)
        print('au au!')

    def prepare(self):
        print('preparando parent!')
```

But if you don't really want to override `prepare` in your subclass, maybe it would make more sense to give the methods different names.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers from the guys and, mainly, from @sahasrara62, I managed to make some changes and arrive at a solution:

```
class Dog:
    nick = 'big'

    def sound(self):
        self.prepare()
    
        print(self.nick)
        print('au au!')

    def prepare(self):
        print('preparando parent!')

class Boxer(Dog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nick = 'little'
    
    def sound(self):
        Dog.sound(self)

    def prepare(self):
        print('preparando box!')

dog = Boxer();
dog.sound()
```

With the following output (preserving states, inclusive):

```
preparando box!
little
au au!
```